# msiexec:How can I show the product name

Tags: winforms, installation

I'm using msiexec.exe /x {GUID} to unistall my application, but it only shows "Are you sure you want to uninstall this product", how can I show the product name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Windows Installer prompt and cannot be customized. Windows installer is showing this message in order to confirm that you want to proceed with uninstall, your MSI doesn't have anything to do with how this prompt is displayed.

For example if you install a French language MSI on English XP, the above message will still be in English even though all strings in the MSI are in French.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of record with Property field named ProductName in the table named Property in msi file. To open the msi and see the tables you can use application named Orca (One Really Cool Application from Microsoft Platform SDK).